# Auto panning to feature from attribute table in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, fields-attributes, data-reviewer, pan

**Is there a way to auto pan to the next feature in a data-set with one click**.

I just used Data Reviewer and when it brings back a list of attributes that need fixing it opens up a "browse features window."

This window allows you to simply click the next arrow to pan to the next broken feature.

In ArcMap without Data Reviewer I find that I have to manually look at each entry for QA/QC i.e. right click, pan to feature, fix problem, lose place, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately, no toolbar buttons that work in that manner.  You could easily make one with addins.  I use a combination of keyboard shortcuts found [here](http://www.esri.com/library/brochures/pdfs/arcgis-desktop-tips.pdf).

Comment: We had a couple of what I later found out were custom written tools to do this at a digitzing job I held. At the time I didn't realize they weren't actually part of ArcGIS. They had varying functionality - some just stepped through, some had interfaces to mark something as completed or not, etc. There are some freely available tools out there - I suggest Googling "arcgis step through selected features" as a starting point. But without knowing more specifically what you are trying to do/check (and what 'broken' means), it's hard to make specific suggestions.

Comment: You might check out the  Main Street Parcel Search plugin from here: http://www.mainstreetgis.com/arcgis.htm.  I don't have it installed but I recalled using it years ago.

Answer (score 3):

This is perfect for an addin [button](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/button/014p0000001z000000/).

Assuming you want to pan to every single in your feature dataset, you can use the OID to do this.

Something like this should give you a few ideas:

```py
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT") 
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
layer = "<name of the layer>"
#Name of OID field
idname = [str(x.name) for x in arcpy.ListFields(layer, "*", "OID")][0]
old_oid = [x[0] for x in arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer, idname)]
#Increment by 1 to advance to next feature.
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management(layer, "NEW_SELECTION","{0}={1}".format(idname, old_oid+1))
df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
```

Making this actually pan would be a little more code, as you'd need to get the extent of the selected feature and then use `df.panToExtent()`.

Making this work when you aren't interested in sequential OIDS would be a little tougher to implement. Depends a lot on how your data is set up, of course.